# Adding a row to JList

Tags: java, mysql, row, jlist

I'm trying to add a row to a JList, but it doesn't happen. I'm using Java + MySQL. But when using `System.out.println()`, it works.

Here is the code for receiving the data:

```
public void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        String student_firstname = resultSet.getString("student_firstname");
        String student_middlename = resultSet.getString("student_middlename");
        String student_lastname = resultSet.getString("student_lastname");

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.addElement("" + student_firstname + " " + student_middlename + " " + student_lastname);
        jList1.setModel(listModel);

    }
}
```

Also, if I try to add the listmodel in `private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` but using defined string, it works, but I need to insert it in this method so that I can get the data from MySQL.

Comment: You are creating a new model and give it to the list once for each row of your result, are you sure this is what you want? With this you can only add the last student in the JList

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you're re-instantiating the `ListModel` and setting it to the JList for every record in the result set, which means that the only thing you're going to see is the last record in the resultSet. Instead, you should be doing something like this:

```
public void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        String student_firstname = resultSet.getString("student_firstname");
        String student_middlename = resultSet.getString("student_middlename");
        String student_lastname = resultSet.getString("student_lastname");


        listModel.addElement("" + student_firstname + " " + student_middlename + " " + student_lastname);

    }

jList1.setModel(listModel);

}
```